# regmatches to return multiple matches from gregexpr

Tags: regex, r

I wanted to grab 2-3 words before and after the word: "help"

I have a block of text as below:

> ....features and lots of greenery to help soothe the nerves...blah blah...cozy up in their plush blankets to help relax the nerves

This is what I did

```
x <- paste("(\\S+\\s+|^)(\\S+\\s+|)(\\S+\\s+|)", treatSym[i], ".?(\\s+\\S+|)(\\s+\\S+|$)(\\s+\\S+|$)", sep="")

matching <- gregexpr(x,text)

regmatches(text, matching, invert = FALSE)
```

I got this error because i'm guessing length(matching) = 2. It works well when there is only 1 match though.

```
Error in regmatches(text, matching, invert = FALSE) : 
  ‘x’ and ‘m’ must have the same length
```

Would there be a better solution to call out the 2-3 words before and after the keyword?

Comment: when sharing code snippets related to your problem, it will be best if they are reproducible examples of your problem. this might force you to modify your code a little but in the end it will help other's to understand you and help you with greater ease

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n` is a vector of length 2 giving the number of words before and after the keyword

```
n <- c(2, 2)
x <- "....features and lots of greenery to help soothe the nerves...blah blah...cozy up in their plush blankets to help relax the nerves"

pat <- sprintf('(?:[a-z]+ ){%s}help(?: [a-z]+){%s}', n[1], n[2])
m <- gregexpr(pat, x, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(x, m)[[1]]
# [1] "greenery to help soothe the" "blankets to help relax the"
```

As a function

```
f <- function(string, keyword, n = c(2,2)) {
  # pat <- sprintf('(?:[a-z]+ ){%s}%s(?: [a-z]+){%s}', n[1], keyword, n[2])
  pat <- sprintf('(?:[a-z]+ ){0,%s}%s(?: [a-z]+){0,%s}', n[1], keyword, n[2])
  m <- gregexpr(pat, string, perl = TRUE)
  regmatches(string, m)[[1]]
}

f(x, 'help', c(1, 2))
# [1] "to help soothe the" "to help relax the"
```

Comment: Thanks, Rawr! I tested it and guessing that n vector is the number of words before and after they keyword. Your solution works well up to 3 but when i put n <- c(4,4), the output is character(0). Any ideas?

Comment: @user5705407 there aren't four words after the second "help" but I have updated the function to work for that case if that's what you what, try it now

Comment: I was about to suggest the same. I see it now. Thanks a lot! Great solution overall

Comment: @user5705407 I wonder why you can't just use `{,%s}` instead of `{0,%s}`

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to split words, get indexes of `help`, and get 2 or 3 words before/after each `help`.

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)
library(SOfun)  ### https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun

x <- "....features and lots of greenery to help soothe the nerves...blah blah...cozy up in their plush blankets to help relax the nerves"
```

#### Option 1: Just get the words

```
### Remove ... and split words
temp <- stri_replace_all_regex(pattern = "[[:punct:]]", replacement = " ", str = x) %>%
        stri_split_fixed(pattern = " ") %>%
        unlist %>%
        .[nchar(.) > 0]

data.frame(word = temp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
getMyRows(pattern = grep(pattern = "help", x = .$word), range = -3:3) %>%
lapply(function(ana){ana[-grep(pattern = "help", x = ana)]})

#[[1]]
#[1] "of"       "greenery" "to"       "soothe"   "the"      "nerves"  
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "plush"    "blankets" "to"       "relax"    "the"      "nerves"
```

If you want to see which words you choose for each `help`, you could try the following.

#### Option 2: Create a data frame

```
temp <- stri_replace_all_regex(pattern = "[[:punct:]]", replacement = " ", str = x) %>%
        stri_split_fixed(pattern = " ") %>%
        unlist %>%
        .[nchar(.) > 0]

data.frame(word = temp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
getMyRows(pattern = grep(pattern = "help", x = .$word), range = -3:3) %>%
lapply(function(ana){ana[-grep(pattern = "help", x = ana)]}) -> temp


do.call(rbind,
        lapply(temp, function(y){
                        data.frame(word = y,
                                   ind = c(-3:-1, 1:3),
                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)}
              )
        )

# ind indicates relative positions of the words. words with negative
# numbers are on left side of help. Words with positive numbers on right.

#       word ind
#1        of  -3
#2  greenery  -2
#3        to  -1
#4    soothe   1
#5       the   2
#6    nerves   3
#7     plush  -3
#8  blankets  -2
#9        to  -1
#10    relax   1
#11      the   2
#12   nerves   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `quanteda` package for something like this.

```
my.string <- "....features and lots of greenery to help soothe the nerves...blah blah...cozy up in their plush blankets to help relax the nerves"

library(quanteda)
kwic(my.string, "help", window = 3, valuetype = "fixed")

                     contextPre keyword         contextPost
[text1, 11]    of greenery to [    help ] soothe the nerves
[text1, 30] plush blankets to [    help ] relax the nerves
```